# Worklight Realm and ClassName Element

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I was going through the following URL:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_adapter_based_authenticator.html

which explains the Implementing adapter-based authenticators. which also what we are using in our project. However, the mysterious part for me is the `<className>` element.

```
<className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
```

My quires are:

- From where the `<className>` value is taken?
- where is`com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator` inside WL?.
- Is there any detailed documentation regarding `<className>`element?

I'm trying to understand what is inside this element and what are its parameters. Regardless my understanding why it is being used, I just want to go deeper in this class element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `classname` node denotes which authenticator type will be used.
You cannot look into it. It is pre-bundled with Worklight.

In this case, it refers to the adapter authenticator. Using `<classname>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</classname>` means that the server-side part of the authenticator is defined in the adapter, and this is what you implement in adapter-based authentication. [See the adapter authentication tutorial in the developer center](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/).

You can also implement your own authenticator, in which case you will define a custom classname: `<className>com.mypackage.MyCustomAuthenticator</className>`, as well as implement it. This class will then reside in your project under the  server\java folder and will be part of your server once deployed. [See the custom authentication tutorial in developer center](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/custom-authenticator-login-module/#customLogin).

Comment: Your answer explained all my quires. I was hoping as curiosity to go deeper inside those predefined classNames which are pre-bundled inside WL. However, the custom authentication tutorial gave me an idea what would I expect inside those pre-bundled classNames and how it might be coded. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to go deep into How the IBM MobileFirst Security modules are implemented?

Instead, you can understand the purpose of implementation and how you can utilize those into your IBM MobileFirst Project.

To learn more about IBM Mobilefirst [Authentication and Security](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/) go to the given link.

You can implement [custom login modules and authenticators](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/custom-authenticator-login-module/) when the ones that are provided by default do not match your requirements.